# Como crear una mascara Dinámica con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask-plugin

tengo en mi código

```
<input id="telefono" type="text" class="form-control" pattern="[0-9]{10}" placeholder=" _ _ _-_ _ _-_ _ _ _">
```

En mi js tengo esto

```
$(document).on("keypress", "#telefono", function(e) {
    var val = elimatephoneMask(this.value)

    if(val.length == 3)
    {
      $('#telefono').unmask()
      if(val == '001')
      {
        $("#telefono").mask("(999) 999-9999999");
        $('#telefono').val(val)
      }else{
        $("#telefono").mask("(999) 999-9999");
        $('#telefono').val(val)
      }
      

    }else if(val.length == 0)
    {
      $('#telefono').unmask()
      $('#telefono').val('')
    }

});

function elimatephoneMask(e)
{
    var s = e.replace(/[_\W]+/g,'');
    return s;
}
```

Valido si los primeros números son 001, en dado caso de si, creo un mask, caso contrario creo otro, todo corre bien, el problema pasa cuando estribo todo el número completo para que entre al if y después lo borro para que entre a mi else, pero al momento de escribir me borra mis primeros 3 números y me deja el cuarto